# Styling button with dynamic text in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am not a iOS developer. I am working on designing GUI for an iOS application to be developed using Appcelerator Titanium.
As far as all the other buttons are concerned, they can be provided with a .png image to style them. But this one type of button which has dynamic text, and thus can have width of various sizes as shown in the image below.

[image]

The screenshot is from Instagram iOS app. It shows the button in navigation bar named `Camera` which is the name of the folder from which image being cropped resides. In the app I'm designing for has a button with same functionality.

I just want to know whether it is possible to add custom styling for this particular type of button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can create a button and set the backgroundImage for the button to be whatever you want

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button

third paragraph

*You can specify background images for each state, as well as button text and a button icon. On iOS, there are button styles which define appearance for each state, even if no button images are set.*

[backgroundLeftCap Property](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-backgroundLeftCap)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but this particular type of button has variable width depending on the text so how will the background image given adapt to that?

Comment: yes I am aware of that... and the platform can handle stretching the background image appropriately see backgroundLeftCap property http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-backgroundLeftCap

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: yes you can add custom styling to this button. As for the varying width, the background image will stretch to fill it.